# Unable to do type verification on a runspace

Tags: powershell, pester

I am using Pester to do some unit testing on a module I am creating and I'm having a bit of trouble with one of my functions that is supposed to return a runspace object.  When I create a runspace object and do a `.GetType()` I see the name listed as LocalRunspace with a fullname of System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.LocalRunspace however when I run`$Runspace -is [LocalRunspace]` or `$Runspace -is [System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.LocalRunspace]` I get the error message below

```
Unable to find type [System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.LocalRunspace]. Make sure that the assembly that contains this type is loaded.
At line:1 char:1
+ $ps.Runspace -is [System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.LocalRunspace]
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Manageme...s.LocalRunspace:TypeName) [], RuntimeException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : TypeNotFound
```

Just trying to figure out what type I should be referencing in order to create the proper validation check.  I know I could fall back on doing comparison to the results of the `.GetType()` but I'd really rather use the normal Pester convention of `Should BeOfType`

Comment: `LocalRunspace` is internal type, thus it can not be expressed with PowerShell type syntax. But you can use `RunspaceIsRemote` property to make sure `Runspace` is local.

Comment: Please [clarify](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) the purpose (The problem you are trying to solve not just how you are trying to implement it) of this test so we can provide a better answer.

Comment: Thanks for the attempt to assist but petserai's answer is sufficient for my purposes

Comment: Check `[System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.Runspace]:: DefaultRunspace.GetType()|Format-List`